# Remove single quote from start of the string and end of the string

Tags: c#, string

I want to remove quote from starting of the string and end of the string. But my existing code is removing all quotes from the string. I tried to replace with `Trim()` method. But no hopes.

**My code here**

```
result = value.Replace("'", "").Split(',').ToList();
```

I tried the following also,

```
result = value.TrimStart(Convert.ToChar("'"))
              .TrimEnd(Convert.ToChar("'"))
              .Split(',')
              .ToList();
```

Please give me the proper way to do this.

Comment: See [String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)  &

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try `.Trim()` like the following:

```
string inputStr = "'some string'";
string outputStr = inputStr.Trim(new char[]{(char)39});
```

Where `(char)39` represents `'`, and the `.Trim()` will remove the first and last `'` from the string; You can try like this as well:

```
string outputStr = inputStr.Trim('\'');
```

You can take a look into this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lIeuVY)

Comment: string outputStr = inputStr.Replace("'",""); shall we use this correct? But why need trim also why this is not working as mentioned in question.

Comment: @BalajiM: The `.Replace` will replace all the occurrences of the specified characters. But the OP wants to remove the `'` at the start and the end that's why i choose `Trim` instead for replace

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
string inputStr = "'some string'";
string outputStr = inputStr.Trim('\'')
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  int indexOfFirst = value.IndexOf('\'');
  string temp = value.Remove(indexOfFirst, 1);
  int indexOfLast = temp.LastIndexOf('\'');         
  temp = temp.Remove(indexOfLast, 1);
```

Hope this was useful.

Comment: when i tried to remove last index , first index removed value is changed. (by using single variable temp )

Answer (score 0):

`if (value.Length >= 2 && value[0] == '\'' && value[value.Length - 1] == '\'') { value = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2); }`

this will check if the first and last char are actually single quote and if so remove it